# Inconsistency between analytical solution and numerical solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation as below:

$$u^{'}=y$$
$$y^{'}=-k_1u-k_3u^3$$

Analytical solution of this equation would be:

$$(u_0,y_0)=(\pm\chi_esech\sqrt{\kappa}\tau,\mp\chi_e\sqrt{\kappa}sech\sqrt{\kappa}\tau  tanh\sqrt{\kappa}\tau)$$
$$\kappa=-k_1\qquad\chi_e=\sqrt{-2k_1\over k_3}$$

Obviously, this solution is not periodic; however, when I solve this differential equation with ode45 in Matlab, the solution is periodic for a specific time interval. I don't know why the numerical solution and analytical one are different from each other.
I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me an answer for this problem. you can find simulation results from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSvp6.png).

Comment: it might help if you explain a bit more about the MatLab answer.... hard to explain it when you don't provide any details about it

Comment: Your "analytical solution" is wrong.  There is a closed-form solution, but it involves Jacobi elliptic functions and is periodic (for appropriate values of parameters).

Comment: @Moo k1 is negative an k3 is positive real numbers.

Comment: What are the initial conditions ? In any manner, as Robert Israel  commented, I think that there is a problem with your analytical solution. Could you provide a set of initial conditions and the values of $k_1,k_3$ you used in Matlab ? AT least for a test.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Assume k1=-0.23 and k3=317. I usesd (0.0001,0.000023) as the initial condition. I added a picture of my simulation result in the first post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RobertIsrael If the analytical solution is wrong why this solution coincide with numerical one in my simulation? you can see the simulation results in my post. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for being too hasty in the previous comment.  Your "analytical solution" is correct, but it is not the general solution: it has no free parameters.  There are three equilibrium points $(u,y) = (0,0), (\pm \sqrt{-k_1/k_3}, 0)$. $(0,0)$ is a saddle, while the other two are centres. Your solutions are homoclinic cycles that start and end at the equilibrium point $(0,0)$ as $\tau \to \pm \infty$.  The other solutions are periodic, and can be written in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions.  One way to see that they should be periodic is that they leave invariant a "potential energy" $V = \dfrac{k_1}{2} u^2 + \dfrac{k_3}{4} u^4 + \dfrac{1}{2} y^2$.
The orbits are all level curves of $V$.

Here's a phase portrait, with your solutions in dark blue and three periodic orbits in cyan.

[image]